# Getting all events for all calendars with Google API Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to get all of a user's events, for all of their calendars on Google Calendar. I'm doing this by first making the call to `gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list`, and then using the IDs retrieved in the call to `gapi.client.calendar.events.list`. However, this is resulting in some very weird results. Here is the code:

```
getAllEvents: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
        // get all calendars that the user has on Google Calendar
        getCalendars = function() {
          gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
              var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({});
              request.execute(function(resp) {
                  if(!resp.error) {
                    var calendarIds = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                      calendarIds.push(resp.items[i].id);
                    }
                    getEvents(calendarIds);
                  }
                  else {
                    deferred.reject(resp.error);
                  }
              });
          });
        },
        // get all events for each calendar that was found
        getEvents = function(calendarIds) {
          var events = [];

          for(var i = 0; i < calendarIds.length; i++) {
            // bind i to function to allow asynchronous functions inside for loop
            (function(cntr) {
              var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                calendarId: calendarIds[i]
              });

              request.execute(function(resp) {
                  if(!resp.error) {
                    for(var j = 0; j < resp.items.length; j++) {
                      console.log(j);
                      events.push(resp.items[j]);
                    }
                  }
                  else {
                    deferred.reject(resp.error);
                  }
              });
            })(i);
          }
          console.log(events);
          deferred.resolve(events);
        };

        // login to google API before making calls
        gapi.auth.authorize({ 
              client_id: this.clientId, 
              scope: this.scopes, 
              immediate: true, 
        }, getCalendars);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
```

This retrieves the calendar IDs correctly, and even retrieves all the events correctly. However, I think the way I'm doing the asynchronous calls is causing some problems. If I `console.log` the `events` array after the inner for loop, it has 110 items but a length of 0 and none of the items can be accessed via their index. If I `console.log` something inside the for loop, it prints after the `console.log(events)`. Lastly, if I `console.log` the value of `j` within the inner for loop, the values are logged out of order, say `0...19`, then `0...86`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Like I said, it's retrieving data correctly but I think something is going wrong with the asynchronous calls. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, the main reason for these strange errors was the use of the for loop with the asynchronous calls. In order to avoid the for loop, I decided to use Angular's promises more to my advantage:

- Get all calendars, and return a promise
- After call to get all calendars completes, create a promise for each event query needed
- use Angular's `$q.all` to make all of the calls using the promises created, THEN return all the events found.

Here's the new code:

```
getAllEvents: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),

        // get all calendars that the user has on Google Calendar
        getCalendars = function() {
          var calDeferred = $q.defer();

          gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
              var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({});
              request.execute(function(resp) {
                  if(!resp.error) {
                    var calendarIds = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                      calendarIds.push(resp.items[i].id);
                    }
                    calDeferred.resolve(calendarIds);
                  }
                  else {
                    calDeferred.reject(resp.error);
                  }
              });
          });

          return calDeferred.promise;
        },
        // get all events for a calendar
        getEvents = function(calendarId) {
          var events = [],
              eventsDeferred = $q.defer();

          var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: calendarId
          });

          request.execute(function(resp) {
              if(!resp.error) {
                for(var j = 0; j < resp.items.length; j++) {
                  events.push(resp.items[j]);
                }
                eventsDeferred.resolve(events);
              }
              else {
                eventsDeferred.reject(resp.error);
              }
          });

          return eventsDeferred.promise;
        },
        getAllEvents = function() {
          getCalendars().then(function (calendarIds) {
            var eventCalls = [];

            // get promise for each calendar event query
            for(var i = 0; i < calendarIds.length; i++) {
              eventCalls.push(getEvents(calendarIds[i]));
            }

            // make all calls to get all events
            $q.all(eventCalls).then(function(results) {
              var aggregatedData = [];

              angular.forEach(results, function (result) {
                  aggregatedData = aggregatedData.concat(result);
              });

              deferred.resolve(aggregatedData);
            });
          },
          function (errorMessage) {
            deferred.reject(errorMessage);
          });
        };

        // login to google API before making calls
        gapi.auth.authorize({ 
              client_id: this.clientId, 
              scope: this.scopes, 
              immediate: true, 
        }, getAllEvents);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
```

Comment: Side note, I feel terribly sad knowing that someone has to implement this by hand and spend n API calls, instead of having a getAllEvents() on the user object.